# Inheritance mapping in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I could imagine it's a bit too early for that, but what's the plan for supporting inheritance in ember-data?
My current use-case is to configure authentication keys for different apps, like user key for Dropbox, user key for Twilio, user key for AppX. I would like to store collection of 'Keys' which are in particular could be a DropboxKey, TwilioKey or AppXKey.
I would see following DS.Model classes:

```
var Account = DS.Model.extend({ name: DS.attr('string') });
var DropboxAccount = Account.extend({ key: DS.attr('string'), secret: DS.attr('string')});
var FastbillAccount = Account.extend({ email: DS.attr('string'), key: DS.attr('string')});
```

Now I would like to do

```
Account.find()
```

Comment: maybe you want to explain a little more of what you're trying to do. Doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: I agree with @MilkyWayJoe. Isn't very clear. Are you wanting to subclass a Key model? Or are you wanting to build relationships? Both are things you can do right now.

Comment: Edited my post, added samples

Comment: In this case, all models that inherit/extend `Account` will have a `name` property as well as the properties you defined manually (such as `key`, `secret`, etc). But since you're creating new models, whenever you call `find` for one of these extended types the Framework will fire a request to *that resource* and not to the account resource, so you need to make sure your API has resources for `DropboxAccount` or that you set the adapter to know these other models should talk to `account`.